# Setting A Function To A Lot Of Symbols

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am a beginner in programming and my question is how do I set a code to a lot of symbols?

Like if I want to set a code to 30 different symbols but the code is the same..
Is there any shorter way to do it than repeating it 30 times?

I heard the flash player version you have will affect a few codes & I have Flash player 11.2 r202

Thank you!

Comment: Make a class with the desired behavior and use those symbols as graphic data. Basically, if you want to have dog, cat and mouse, you need class Animal which has some fields like speed, weight, and, last but not least, image.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve exactly, a code example or at least a use case would be nice

Comment: @Organis I do not get what you mean :(

Comment: @Oran153 You should learn OOP approach then, because it is OOP basics.